# access animated elements via their queue key?

Tags: jquery

Can I stop an animation in a custom-named queue without access to the animated elements?

```
$(complictedSelector).animate( 
     {opacity: .5}, 
     {duration: 10000, queue: 'hover'} );
```

My naive attempt at using `$stop( 'hover' )` doesn't work :-)

It seems I **do** need the elements.  So... is there a way to access animated elements via their queue key/name?

By queue key I mean a string passed into the options (in this example, 'hover').

*[( As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string. )](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)*

Comment: I don't see any way of doing that. The queues are tied to the elements since multiple elements can have separate queues with the same name.

Comment: All of the queue based methods have a required element argument or require being called on selected elements.

Comment: shame that; would ne nice to be able to shut all queues-with-the-same-name down at once. I will have to do some bookkeeping to keep a copy of my elements around then...

Comment: If there is a way of doing it, it's through undocumented methods which will add on a layer of maintenance that may have to be done with each update of jQuery. Probably better to just do it yourself as you say.

Comment: You could iterate over the timers in `$.timers` and check the `.queue` property of each item. The corresponding element of the timer is saved as `.elem` - but that is not an official way... :)

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely work, until the $.timers array is removed/renamed or it's members lose the .queue property. See `.data("events')`. It would definitely work as a temporary solution though.

Comment: I won't recommend doing it that way. I've just tested it and thought I should mention this possibility - although it's really nasty^^

Answer (score 0):

> *"Can I stop an animation in a custom-named queue without access to the animated elements?"*

I don't suggest that this is at all efficient, but:

```
$(":animated").stop('hover');
// or even
$("*").stop('hover');
```

I guess you have to balance the ease of coding the inefficient one-liner against having more infrastructure in place to keep a reference to the animated elements, perhaps test the speed, and make your own decision how to proceed.